# EnableRewind and leaveOpen on StreamReader are not stopping the request from being disposed

Tags: .net-core

I'm using ApplicationInsights and I want to add the request, and after that the response, to the logging properties.

To achieve this I am implementing my own `ITelemetryInitializer`. It looks exactly like this.

```cs
    public class MyInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public MyInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;

            if (requestTelemetry == null || _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request == null 
                || requestTelemetry.Properties.ContainsKey("RequestBody"))
            {
                return;
            }

            var request = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request;
            request?.EnableRewind();

            if (request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Post.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                || request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Put.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
                {
                    var requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("RequestBody", requestBody);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In startup I've added this

```cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyInitializer>();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

The error I get is:

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: FileBufferingReadStream.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed()
```

---

I've used `.EnableRewind` as well as instructing the `StreamReader` to leave the file open. Despite this my request is still null when it actually hits my controller, or even when it hits my initializer again for a second pass (setting the response information).

Any suggestions are welcome.

---

Additionally I tried adding a piece of middleware to ensure `.EnableRewind` was on for everything, but this did nothing. I'd prefer not to have to add any additional middleware since I'd like there to be no other dependencies.

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableRewind();
    await next();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always the solution ends up being a single line of code. I owe Mr Gunnar Peipman a thanks for his blog post [Reading request body in ASP.NET Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/aspnet-core-request-body/).

The line:
`request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

The code

```cs
public class MyInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;

        if (requestTelemetry == null || _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request == null
                                     || requestTelemetry.Properties.ContainsKey("RequestBody"))
        {
            return;
        }

        var request = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request;
        request?.EnableRewind();

        if (request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Post.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            || request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Put.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
            {
                var requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("RequestBody", requestBody);
            }
        }
    }
}
```